# Formatting Dates For Output

Tags: perl, date

I have viewed a lot of other similar threads but most of them are related to formatting current system time, as are most of the exmaples online. I am parsing a log file and have an incoming date that I want output in a different format.  Here is the code I have to test with:

```
use Date::Format;

my $formatdate="";

# input date format is mm/dd/yy
my $unformatdate="04/02/13";

#format the date
$formatdate=time2str("%B %e %Y", $unformatdate);
#print the output
print "Unformatted Date is: $unformatdate\n";
print "Formatted date 1 is: $formatdate\n";
```

Here is the output.  The format is correct, the value is not.  I assume it is becuase time2str() does not like the input format.

```
Unformatted Date is: 04/02/13
Formatted date 1 is: December 31 1969
```

I also tried input like this:

```
my $unformatdate="04-020-2013";
```

Comment: Try to use DateTime perl module. http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-1.04/lib/DateTime.pm

Answer (score 3):

`time2str` expects a unix time value ( seconds since epoch ). You're giving it a string that gets mapped to the integer 0 and thus you get back the beginning of the epoch.

If the dates are all the same format, the easiest thing to do would be to strip out day, month and year using `split` and simply use `sprintf` to create the string you want.

The library you actually want to use in the general case is [`Date::Parse`](http://p3rl.org/Date%3a%3aParse).

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to do date parsing with [Time::Piece](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html#Date-Parsing), since it has been a core module since Perl 5.9:

```
use Time::Piece;

my $t = Time::Piece->strptime('04/02/13','%D');
print $t->strftime('%B %e %Y');
```

#### Output:

```
April  2 2013
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some more checking and this:

```
use Date::Manip::Date;
my $unformatdate="04/02/13";


$date->parse($unformatdate);
print $date->printf("%F\n");
```

outputs:

```
Tuesday, April 02, 2013
```

Comment: Date::Manip hasn't been a good suggestion for years. The DateTime modules are far better and Time::Piece has been a core module since 5.10.